# Prolog files: What does "run "swipl -f main.pl"" mean?

Tags: prolog, osx-lion

I tried various combinations of brackets and single quotes after the ?- prompt in SWI Prolog on Mac OSX. Nothing worked. Is this command supposed to load a bunch of files at once? Do I type something before I even get to the ?- prompt?

If someone can tell me exactly what to type for #1 below it would be wonderful. (I'm not a programmer, but I've been trying to find a simple expert system shell for my intro to cognitive science class to play around with. I have tried the Amzi birds thing about a million times and get nothing but errors in Amzi as well as SWI). THANKS!

A Prolog Expert System (APES)
 http://apes.sourceforge.net/
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Running:

1. install swi-prolog (should work on any ISO-Standard Prolog Interpreter, but this is untested)
2. run "swipl -f main.pl"
3. enter "start."

UPDATE: 
(Thank hardmath and user882813 so much!) I got a command does not exist error with "swipl -f main.pl", so I started SWI Prolog abd loaded main.pl manually. Here is the code for main.pl:

```
% A Prolog Expert System (APES)
% http://apes.sourceforge.net/
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

:- ensure_loaded('engine.pl').
:- ensure_loaded('tokenizer.pl').
:- ensure_loaded('parser.pl').
:- ensure_loaded('knowledge/knowledge.pl').
:- ensure_loaded('knowledge/groups/*.pl').
:- ensure_loaded('helpers.pl').
:- ensure_loaded('processor.pl').

start:-
    %dynamic((::)/2),
    write('_____________________________________________________'),
    nl,nl,
    loop_read_in(_).

loop_read_in(X):-
    % from tokenizer.pl (clocksin & mellish, "programming in prolog"):
    read_in(X),
    process(X),
    loop_read_in(_).

loop_read_in(X):-
    read_in(X), 
    not(process(X)),
    !,fail.
```

But here is what happened: When I enter start I get a file does not exist error: 
    ERROR: /Users/leesebastiani/prologfiles/main.pl:10:
        source_sink `knowledge/groups/*.pl' does not exist

But when I tried to load THAT manually I got this:
    ?- ['knowledge/groups/*.pl'].
    ERROR: /Users/leesebastiani/prologfiles/main.pl:10:
        source_sink `knowledge/groups/*.pl' does not exist
    Warning: /Users/leesebastiani/prologfiles/main.pl:10:
        Goal (directive) failed: user:ensure_loaded(knowledge/groups/*.pl)

I want to make this easy for my students. Here's my complete last session:

```
?- ['main.pl'].
%  engine.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 64 clauses
%  tokenizer.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 62 clauses
%  parser.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 32 clauses
%  knowledge/knowledge.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 17 clauses
ERROR: /Users/leesebastiani/prologfiles/main.pl:10:
    source_sink `knowledge/groups/*.pl' does not exist
Warning: /Users/leesebastiani/prologfiles/main.pl:10:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:ensure_loaded(knowledge/groups/*.pl)
%  helpers.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 24 clauses
%  processor.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 12 clauses
% main.pl compiled 0.01 sec, 227 clauses
true.

?- ['knowledge/groups/*.pl'].
% knowledge/groups/feline.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 2 clauses
% knowledge/groups/pet.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 5 clauses
true.

?- ['main.pl'].
ERROR: /Users/leesebastiani/prologfiles/main.pl:10:
    source_sink `knowledge/groups/*.pl' does not exist
Warning: /Users/leesebastiani/prologfiles/main.pl:10:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:ensure_loaded(knowledge/groups/*.pl)
% main.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?-
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

For me, this works (on Mac OS 10.8.5):

`$ git clone https://github.com/fsteeg/apes.git

[...]

$ cd com.quui.apes/src/

$ swipl -f main.pl

?- start.`

I used the GitHub version, but the code should be the same. Could it be an issue with your version of SWI-Prolog? I installed mine with Homebrew (http://brew.sh/):

`$ brew install swi-prolog

[...]

$ swipl --version

SWI-Prolog version 6.0.2 for i386-darwin12.5.0`

If this does not help, could you provide some details on your original issue when running `swipl -f main.pl`?

Comment: Fabian, you are the best! I am running OS 10.7.5 and Prolog SWI 6.4.1. Here's what happened: [lee-sebastianis-macbook-pro:~/prologfiles/apes-0.2.0/src] leesebastiani% swipl -f main.pl
swipl: Command not found.

Comment: I don't mind starting SWI manually, but here's what happens:?- ['main.pl'].
%  engine.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 64 clauses
%  tokenizer.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 62 clauses
%  parser.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 32 clauses
%  knowledge/knowledge.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 17 clauses
ERROR: /Users/leesebastiani/prologfiles/apes-0.2.0/src/main.pl:10:
 source_sink `knowledge/groups/*.pl' does not exist
Warning: 
 Goal (directive) failed: user:ensure_loaded(knowledge/groups/*.pl)
%  helpers.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 24 clauses
%  processor.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 12 clauses
% main.pl compiled 0.01 sec, 227 clauses
true.

Comment: @Lee Since that error mentions the source files in the `knowledge/groups/` subdirectory, I guess the way you manually load SWI or the file does not see that subdirectory. I'd try to install SWI-Prolog with Homebrew to have an installation that works on the command line (to fix the original 'Command not found.' issue).

Comment: brew install worked.  Mac users should NOT use the downloads link on their website: http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable

Answer (score 0):

The command "swipl -f main.pl" is something that is entered at the OS command prompt, not within SWI-Prolog at the ?- prompt.

The command executes the top-level command interpreter and loads the Prolog source file `main.pl`.

Comment: Thank you both so much! I got a command does not exist error, so I loaded main.pl manually. Here is the code for main.pl:

Answer (score 0):

In this case ”swipl -f main.pl”  is a command to be entered in command-line prompt which starts swi-prolog and loads main program file.

If you already started SWI-Prolog then just open main.pl file from APES distrubution via File ⇒ Open menu item then type "start." (without quotes) and press enter.

**Upd:** I got the same error about  `:- ensure_loaded('knowledge/groups/*.pl').` line and just replaced it with two lines with exact file names in place of `*.pl`:

```
:- ensure_loaded('knowledge/groups/feline.pl').
:- ensure_loaded('knowledge/groups/pet.pl').
```

Not sure this is a right way to solve this problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

The AMZI tutorial is quite out of date. Trying to get it running with no knowledge of Prolog looks like a world of pain.
You might want to find something else. It's rather too bad - it's a great tutorial.

If you're brand new to expert systems, let me suggest CLIPS

http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/

Prolog isn't an expert systems shell on it's own. Prolog's a programming language. Of course it'd be a wonderful choice for writing such a shell.